# Strange banding in output raster after weighted overlay

Tags: arcgis-10.0, spatial-analyst, overlay, reclassify

I am trying to conduct a weighted overlay. I have two rasters, one is a continuous slope raster that I reclassified to have 6 classes (8-bit signed integer), and one is an elevation raster that I also reclassified to 6 classes (also 8-bit signed integer).

My inputs look like this:

[image: inputs]

My output looks like this:

[image: output]

Any idea what could possibly be going wrong?

I've never had an output like this before.

Comment: You got an error or a warning (look underneath the tool's title)...what was it?

Comment: I got neither. when I look at results under geoprocessing it says that it successfully worked with no errors

Comment: @DanPatterson is refering to the warning indicator next to your Output Raster name parameter. It may be there because the tool dialog you have opened is from the results page, and therefore that raster name now already exists.

Comment: oh that warning indicator is just there because I took a screenshot of my inputs after the fact by clicking on it from my results page. I found out that my issue was simply that statistics did not get recalculated when I reclassified my rasters (doh!)

Comment: You might post that as an answer - it's ok to answer your own question after a period of time (8 hours I think) as well as accept it, but that takes a bit more waiting (48 hours I believe). Because you've provided a graphic example of the results, I think an answer pointing to lack of statistic recalculation may help others in the future. You might also edit the question title to mention 'strange banding in weighted overlay results raster' or something similar to more accurately describe the issue/question.

Answer (score 2):

I found out that my issue was simply that statistics did not get recalculated when I reclassified my rasters